# xcode instruments causing app crash

Tags: crash, xcode-instruments

I am using xcode Instruments to track Allocations and Leaks. My app is crashing though.  It does not crash when running the regular debug or release builds standalone, only when under Instruments:

Any thoughts ideas very gratefully received....

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0002b2e0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34499c96 objc_msgSend + 14
1   ZZZ Test Suite                  0x000a3d74 0x95000 + 60788
2   CoreFoundation                  0x308e4c3c -[NSObject(NSObject) release] + 24
3   CoreFoundation                  0x308e519a CFRelease + 62
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308e7eb4 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 140
5   Foundation                      0x341b41c4 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 92
6   UIKit                           0x309e5f08 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5784
7   GraphicsServices                0x30269e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30957a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30959838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
12  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
13  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
14  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
15  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
16  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
17  ZZZ Test Suite                  0x0009665c 0x95000 + 5724
18  ZZZ Test Suite                  0x00096604 0x95000 + 5636
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running it through the analyser first.  You can run it from xcode from the |product| menu then select Analyze.  It's a static analyser (clang) that analyses your code when it builds so any problems causing your code to crash at runtime could well be visible through static analysis.  Give it a try and fix any problems it throws up then try instruments again.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I did not know about the Analyze tool, and it helped me find several leaks! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to what Ian says above:
set the Environment variable "NSZombieEnabled" to YES
and you will hopefully have a more informative fail.

(In XCode 4 the Environment Variables is found under "Edit Scheme" and select "Debug")